# How to check if Google App Engine python27 runs thread safe mode or not?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Please help how it is possible to detect if python27 runtime is run in thread safe mode or not for code?

For example to notify that module is not compatible or apply threading code if required.

I want to port some code to python27 as thread safe and some as not thread safe but not understand how it works in Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to change your app.yaml and your app is going to run in threads

```
threadsafe: true
```

You will not be notified if your code is not threadsafe, this is something that you will have to figure out on your own. For example if you have a global variable that you're making changes in a request, then you might have issues. But in general it's not something that will throw and an error or anything, it will be just inconsistent and you might run into troubles later if you're not aware of the concept.

Comment: I know how to switch threads in python27 but not understand limitation for example if all GAE API is thread safe and need to detect threading without global variables which I will set - if it not possible it is little problem with manual configuration.

Want to port GAE python/2.5 on GAE python/2.7.

Comment: @Chameleon there is no specific documentation on GAE on how to make your program thread-safe.. here is I guess a start.. just to figure out if your code is thread-safe or not.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Comment: I have experience in distributed or thread programming so not need wiki articles - too easy for me. The point of question is Google App Engine limitation in threading and specific behaviors.

Comment: @Chameleon well if you do understand.. Then you should understand that that line in app.yaml is just something that will enable threads or not.. Is not going to check if your data is correct.. It will just going to run stuff in threads..

Comment: I think it is not as such simple that one line in app.yaml run threads or not. Why 1st how it will be billed or not, 2nd what is timespan of thread created in handler (infinite or limited), 3rd if transaction with dn.model or ndb.model is thread safe or not, 4rd what will be memory overhead what class of server is need for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have "some thread safe and some not thread safe". That's impossible. If *some* code is not thread safe, then *none* of the code is thread safe. That's just how thread safety works.

Comment: You talk about something else that not answers question. You are right **thread safe code** could not contain not thread safe code but **no thread safe code** could contain both of them.

GAE allow both none thread safe only or thread safe only and questions is how to detect which mode is it. There is no sense to rewrite large code base to thread safe or it not possible in limited time - it is not pragmatic and costy.